# how to retrieve a dictionary's / objects' key value pair in nested dictionary in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object

I am trying to make a **flashcard application** to try and simplify data.
I think that this isn't a very difficult doubt but I am unable to find an answer from google.

1. I want only the key url and the value to be shown from the nested dictionary
2. I want to display the route in the form of a arrow map like: `abcd->cd->d->url:value`

my data ex:

```
abcd = {
"ab": {
    "a": {
        "country": "",
        "url": ""
    },
    "b": {
        "country": "",
        "url": ""
    }
},
"cd": {
    "c": {
        "country": "",
        "url": ""
    },
    "d": {
        "country": "",
        "url": "value"
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I am not sure how to start. I know of object.keys(), but I can't get an idea how to apply it...

Comment: to nested dictionaries

Comment: Object.keys will return you an array of the keys "ab", "cd" ... -> then you can do a forEach to iterate over the keys and do the same logic with the nested keys

Comment: I'm not sure how I can do a recursion with forEach() for many layers of nesting and I'm not sure, even if I can make a recursion, how to assign my required output to a variable as a string.

Comment: why do you need recursion?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the code given below which works for this object only ...

Note that there are a lot of better ways you can approach this .. this is a simple enough one

```js
let abcd = {
"ab": {
    "a": {
        "country": "",
        "url": "fff"
    },
    "b": {
        "country": "",
        "url": "fff"
    }
},
"cd": {
    "c": {
        "country": "",
        "url": "ddd"
    },
    "d": {
        "country": "",
        "url": "value"
    }
}
}

function getKeyValue(obj){
      const result = []
      for(let prop in obj){

            if(typeof obj[prop] === "object"){
                  for(let pr in obj[prop]){
                   result.push(`${prop}->${pr}->url->${obj[prop][pr].url }`)
                  }
             
            }

      }
      return result

}
    
console.log(getKeyValue(abcd))
```

Comment: I was wondering of a recursive solution because I may not use only 4 layers of nesting... I do not know how to assign many variable names... the only thing I can come up is by assigning a variable as: for(let i=0;i<*i don't know how to find this*;i++){let a+i=individual key name}